# Background Images not displayed correctly on Iphone and Ipad

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I have already asked a question similar to this an thought my problem was fixed, but it isn't.

Following code is used for all background-images (image path not always the same):

```
.bg-1 { 
background: url('../Dateien/sharkGround1920.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

works great on all devices even IMac, but is displayed incorrectly on Iphone and Ipad.

I do want the background-size to be 'cover' as this just looks best for what I'm using it.

I figured out, that when I test the site on a responive-check-site on the internet, I can reproduce the bad Iphone look of my website by increasing the devices height and leaving the width fixed.

My Website:
http://www.unterwasserfotografie-thomas-uhl.de/

The Test-Website:
http://responsivepx.com/

Funny thing: I can test my site on all test websites around the web and it always looks great on Iphone-setup. As soon as testing on a real Iphone the images look like zoomed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Christin you should insert a media queries and replace the background-attachment for "scroll". Please see below:

`@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){ 
    .bg-1 { 
        background: url('../Dateien/sharkGround1920.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll !important;
    }
}`

Comment: Is Iphone not able to display scroll?
I want the images to do that fancy bootstrap-scolling and it works great on every android device using Firefox.

Comment: with this replacement, they will work on Ipad and Iphone normally. Have you tried?

Comment: Ok I've changed it on the first background image and it works, but i would like to have that scroll-effect on desktop devices...

Comment: this will required js parallax... is not that can fix only with css I'm afraid, I only know this website that is the same effect as desktop http://www.freddiegrubb.com

Comment: I could add a media query that sets the scroll to fixed for devices that have a width > 1000px ?!

Comment: not really, with that media queries will affect only width (mobile and tablets) less than 768pixel

Comment: Could you vote in my answer? I believe the problem it was solved